# How to plot a pandas timeseries using months/year resolution (with few lines of code)?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, pandas

Assume we want to plot a time series, e.g.:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a=pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2010-01-01',end='2014-01-01' , freq='D')
b=pd.Series(np.randn(len(a)), index=a)
b.plot()
```

The result is a figure in which the x-axis has years as labels, I would like to get month-year labels. Is there a fast way to do this (possibly avoiding the use of tens of lines of complex code calling matplotlib)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pandas does some really weird stuff to the `Axes` objects, making it hard to avoid matplotlib calls.

Here's how I would do it

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd


a = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2010-01-01',end='2014-01-01' , freq='D')
b = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(a)), index=a)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(b.index, b)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m'))
```

which give me:
[image]

Comment: thx, is it also possible to set the granularity of the x axis, e.g. a label for each month?

Comment: yes. then you have use the `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(N))` where `N` is your tick interval in months.