# Timeserie datetick problems when using pandas.DataFrame.plot method

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot, datetime-format

I just discovered something really strange when using `plot` method of `pandas.DataFrame`. I am using pandas `0.19.1`. Here is my MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd

t = pd.date_range('1990-01-01', '1990-01-08', freq='1H')
x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(t)), index=t)

fig, axe = plt.subplots()
x.plot(ax=axe)
plt.show(axe)

xt = axe.get_xticks()
```

When I try to format my xticklabels I get strange beahviours, then I insepcted objects to understand and I have found the following:

- `t[-1] - t[0] = Timedelta('7 days 00:00:00')`, confirming the `DateTimeIndex` is what I expect;
- `xt = [175320, 175488]`, `xticks` are integers but they are not equals to a number of days since epoch (I do not have any idea about what it is);
- `xt[-1] - xt[0] = 168` there are more like index, there is the same amount that `len(x) = 169`.

This explains why I cannot succed to format my axe using:

```
axe.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(byhour=(0,6,12,18)))
axe.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%a %H:%M"))
```

The first raise an error that there is to many ticks to generate
The second show that my first tick is  `Fri 00:00` but it should be `Mon 00:00` (in fact `matplotlib` assumes the first tick to be `0481-01-03 00:00`, oops this is where my bug is).

[image: Axis Ticks Numbering bug]

**It looks like there is some incompatibility between `pandas` and `matplotlib` integer to date conversion** but I cannot find out how to fix this issue.

If I run instead:

```
fig, axe = plt.subplots()
axe.plot(x)
axe.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%a %H:%M"))
plt.show(axe)

xt = axe.get_xticks()
```

Everything works as expected but I miss all cool features from `pandas.DataFrame.plot` method such as curve labeling, etc. And here `xt = [726468.  726475.]`.

How can I properly format my ticks using `pandas.DataFrame.plot` method instead of `axe.plot` and avoiding this issue?

**Update**

The problem seems to be about origin and scale (units) of underlying numbers for date representation. Anyway I cannot control it, even by forcing it to the correct type:

```
t = pd.date_range('1990-01-01', '1990-01-08', freq='1H', origin='unix', units='D')
```

There is a discrepancy between matplotlib and pandas representation. And I could not find any documentation of this problem.

Comment: Did you try the solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945971/pandas-timeseries-plot-setting-x-axis-major-and-minor-ticks-and-labels ?

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620712/how-to-plot-a-pandas-timeseries-using-months-year-resolution-with-few-lines-of?rq=1 Since it's unclear what you would be missing when using the matplotlib command ("cool stuff etc." is completely imprecise), it's hard to help you here.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I would like to keep my call to DataFrame.plot, at least because it handles labels for legend.

Comment: Could this be a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I wonder why I have date rangeing from Year 0481 when I explicitly have set it to 1990. I think when I will understand this, many things will find it answer. Thank you for pointing out the XY problem, but until now I do not feel it like this.

Comment: @tmrlvi, Thank you for pointing this out. I have added a picture of my problem

Comment: The date representation used by pandas is simply different from that of matplotlib. So you cannot use a matplotlib formatter for the dates produced by pandas. The question is, would you like to be stuck with this (the Y) or would you like to tell us the actual problem (the X in the XY-problem).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, Is there pandas formatters? Where are described date representation?

Comment: No, there are no pandas formatters. But that is not a problem, because as in the question I linked to, you can use the matplotlib plot command and format the axes to your liking.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, there is a way to enforce xticks through DataFrame.plot(). Thank you anyway.

Comment: Sure, but that was not the question you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are going for? Note I shortened the date_range to make it easier to see the labels.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.dates as dates

t = pd.date_range('1990-01-01', '1990-01-04', freq='1H')
x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(t)), index=t)

# resample the df to get the index at 6-hour intervals
l = x.resample('6H').first().index

# set the ticks when you plot. this appears to position them, but not set the label
ax = x.plot(xticks=l)

# set the display value of the tick labels
ax.set_xticklabels(l.strftime("%a %H:%M"))
# hide the labels from the initial pandas plot
ax.set_xticklabels([], minor=True)
# make pretty
ax.get_figure().autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

[image: Like this?]