# count values in one pandas series based on date column and other column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have several columns of data and they are in pandas dataframe. the data looks like

```
           cus_id   timestamp       values    second_val
0          10173    2010-06-12        39.0      1
1          95062    2010-09-11        35.0      2 
2          171081   2010-07-05        39.0      1 
3          122867   2010-08-18        39.0      1
4          107186   2010-11-23        0.0       3
5          171085   2010-09-02        0.0       2
6          169767   2010-07-03        28.0      2
7          80170    2010-03-23        39.0      2
8          154178   2010-10-02        37.0      2
9          3494     2010-11-01        0.0       1
.
.
.
.
5054054    1716139  2012-01-12        0.0     2
5054055    1716347  2012-01-18        28.0    1
5054056    1807501  2012-01-21        0.0     1
```

there are 0 values data which appears in values column and it appears on different days. I tried to group all second_val values for each month when the values column data at that time equal to zero to plot them properly and I did it by using

```
Jan10 = df.second_val[df['timestamp'].str.contains('2010-01')][df['values']==0].sum()
Feb10 = df.second_val[df['timestamp'].str.contains('2010-02')][df['values']==0].sum()
Mar10 = df.second_val[df['timestamp'].str.contains('2010-03')][df['values']==0].sum()
.
. 
.
. 
Jan12 = df.second_val[df['timestamp'].str.contains('2012-01')][df['values']==0].sum()
Feb12 = df.second_val[df['timestamp'].str.contains('2012-02')][df['values']==0].sum()


Months = ['2010-01', '2010-02', '2010-03', '2010-04' . . . . ., '2012-01', '2012-02']
Months_Orders = [Jan10, Feb10, Mar10, Apr10, . . . . ..  ., Jan12, Feb12]

plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
plt.scatter(x = Months, y = Months_Orders)
```

like if 0 appear for 10 days in jan10 and sum of second_val data is 20. then it should give me 20 for January month
e.g

```
  cus_id   timestamp       values    second_val
    0          10173    2010-01-10        0.0      1
    .
    .
    13          95062    2010-01-11        0.0      2 
    34          171081   2010-01-23        0.0      1
```

Is there any way to make better by writing in a function or any built-in pandas way. I tried my previous question solution but it was different and didn't work properly for me so I use this hard coded and it seems inefficient. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC

```
df.timestamp=pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)
df=df[df['values']==0]# filter it before groupby 
df.groupby(df.timestamp.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')).second_val.sum()# using groupby after filter to get what you need, group key is format %Y-%m
```

Comment: how can I plot it either scatter or line plot.  I tried to plot like this.  df.groupby(df.timestamp.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')).second_val.sum().plot() . ......bt x-axis has no data to show. . I mean how i can put months on x-axis. Thanks a lot, . your code works perfectly fine to count values .

Comment: I am trying to plot months on x-axis, but getting nothing on x-axis , just written timestamp on x-axis.

Comment: @Rio FYI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620712/how-to-plot-a-pandas-timeseries-using-months-year-resolution-with-few-lines-of

Comment: thanks , I am trying in this way. bt since i am a bit new that why I am a bit struggling. df.groupby(df.timestamp.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')).second_val.sum()                .       fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.date, df)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')) . i am getting this error. . AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'toordinal'